# random numbers in a range that can appear only two times in python 3.9.5

Tags: python, random

I want a way to generate random numbers that can repeat only twice, I am not using decimals and I my range wont go above 1000.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: searching for hours in the internet, because I dont know how I should approach this. @Exitare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to sample from a list without replacement. Just make every number from your desired range appear twice in the list:

```py
import random

n_samples = 10  # or however many random numbers you need
random_numbers = random.sample(2 * list(range(1001)), n_samples)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean:

Shuffle an array [0, 1, ..., n, 0, 1, ..., n] as follows:

```
import random

n=10 # Upper bound of interval [0, n)
arr=[i for i in range(n)]+[i for i in range(n)]
random.shuffle(arr)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a random number may I suggest using `random.randint(1,1000)`.
Then for appending the generated number to a list only if that number does not occur in the list twice you can use the following code.

```
lst = []
occurrences =2
if occurances == lst.count(generated_number):
    lst.append(generated_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest might be:

```
import random
lrand = [j for j in range(1000)] 
lrand += lrand
random.shuffle(lrand)
```

now you can either iterate through or pop off values:

```
next_val = lrand.pop()
```